# Why do I need to recompile widgetsets everytime I restart my computer? (Vaadin)

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, vaadin, vaadin7

Everytime I restart my computer or include a new dependency in my POM - my webapp fails to start with

> Failed to load the widgetset: /myproject/VAADIN/widgetsets/my.company.ProjectWidgetSet/my.company.ProjectWidgetSet.nocache.js

I recompile widgetsets, some times several times in a row. Sometimes I even have to delete a project from Tomcat7 and reinstall it. I also do "clean install" with Maven. Then it starts normally. And may be not - then I just have to repeat some of this actions and pray.

What is happening?

I use Tomcat7 and Vaadin 7.4.2

Comment: do you have two contradicting/racing configs?  is your widgetset.gwt.xml managed automagically and regenerates all the time due to e.g. SNAPSHOT widgets? what relevance does tomcat have here? you deploy to it?  or use it in your ide?  please provide more infos about the environment and maybe the addons/libraries you are using.

Comment: have you made sure that the browser's cache was deleted?

Comment: Besides what @cfrick requested, please post your pom file

Comment: **do you have two contradicting/racing configs?** I dont know what is it, probably not. **is your widgetset.gwt.xml managed automagically and regenerates all the time due to e.g. SNAPSHOT widgets?** I dont know. How can I find it out? **what relevance does tomcat have here? you deploy to it? or use it in your ide?** I deploy to it using Eclipse. **please provide more infos about the environment and maybe the addons/libraries you are using.** I use Ubuntu 14.04. I also have posted my POM in this thread.